# JavaScript Error andDebugging

Tags: javascript

I'm following a tutorial on how to use OMDb API and create a system that can search for movies, but mine is not working. The tutorial am following is the same with mine and it working but mine is not working, Any help please.This is js the source code:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
$('#searchForm').on('submit', (e) => {
  let searchText = $('#searchText').val();
  getMovies(searchText);
  e.preventDefault();
});
});

function getMovies(searchText){
//The Open Movie Database
axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com?s='+searchText);
$.then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  let movies = response.data.Search;
  let output ='';
  $.each(movies, (index, movie) =>{
    output += '
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="well text-center">
     <img src="${movie.Poster}"> 
     <h5>${movie.Title}</h5>
     <a onclick="movieSelected('${movie.imdbID}')" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Movie Details</a>
     </div>
     </div>
     ';
  });

  $('#movies').html(output);
})

.catch((err) =>
  console.log(err);
});

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Movies</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/cyborg/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default" >
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Movie Info</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h3 class="text-center">Search For Any Movie</h3>
      <form id="searchForm">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchText" placeholder="Search Movie">
      <br><input type="submit" value="Search Movies">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="container">
  <div id="movies" class="row"></div>
  </div>


  <script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Your help is highly appreciated, THANKS in advance

Comment: Please define _"not working"_

Comment: FYI, JavaScript does not do multi-line strings within single or double quotes. Your console should have pointed this out. You can use template literals though ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Your `axios.get()` result is never used. And what even is `$.then`? I highly doubt the tutorial and your code are _"the same"_

Comment: Im pretty sure that you need an api key to access this api i don't see anywhere where you added a key to your request

Answer (score 0):

Provided you're either using ES6-level JavaScript, or a transpiler which will handle ES6 syntax and translate it to older JavaScript for you, you need to do this:

```
        output += `
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="well text-center">
         <img src="${movie.Poster}"> 
         <h5>${movie.Title}</h5>
         <a onclick="movieSelected('${movie.imdbID}')" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Movie Details</a>
         </div>
         </div>
         `;
```

...that is, you must surround the above text and code with backticks, not single quotes.